# How many bytes will Django/Postgres use for a decimal field?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, decimal

I would like to like to store a percentage with two decimal places (0 to 100). Thus a decimal field (5 digits total) seems like a good choice, but `smallint` would also get the job done with only two bytes.

How many bytes would be utilized in the database for this configuration of decimal field? And as a follow-up question, how would I query Postgres to investigate the details of the data structure used behind the scenes?

Comment: Google search "postgres data type sizes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) says:

> The actual storage requirement is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus three to eight bytes overhead.

That would be between 5 and 10 bytes in your case.

But storage size should be the last of your concerns here:

- Depending on the types of the fields before and after that number, you might not save as much space as you think, because some data types are aligned at 4 or 8 byte boundaries, and you might lose some of the saved space to padding anyway.
- If you use a lot of arithmetic operations on these data (number crunching), `smallint` or `integer` will perform much better than `numeric`.
- On the other hand, you'll have to shift the comma around during arithmetical processing. That is fast, but might make your code less readable, resulting in a maintenance burden.

To learn about the storage and processing of `numeric`, you'd have to browse the source code.